# How to preserve Fortran array bounds in ASSOCIATE block?

Tags: arrays, fortran

I would like to preserve array bounds in associate block as:

```
integer a(2:4,2)
associate (b => a(:,1))
    print *, lbound(b), ubound(b)
end associate
```

I expect the bounds of `b` is `2` and `4`, but in fact they are `1` and `3`. How to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are associating to a subarray, its boundaries always start at 1. Try

```
 print *, lbound(a(:,1),1)
```

AFAIK you can not use the pointer remapping trick in `associate` construct. Specifically: "[If the selector is an array, the associating entity is an array with a lower bound for each dimension equal to the value of the intrinsic LBOUND(selector).](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/compbg/v121v141/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlf141.bg.doc/language_ref/associatestmt.html)"

But you can of course use pointers

```
integer,target :: a(2:4,2)

integer,pointer :: c(:)


associate (b => a(:,1))
    print *, lbound(b), ubound(b)
end associate

c(2:4) => a(:,1)
print *, lbound(c), ubound(c)

end
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimir! The reason why I use ASSOCIATE block is to avoid extra declaration (e.g. pointer). Hope this can be supported in future.

Comment: @JohnE It was just the end of the test program. It can probably be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I think that more elegant way to preserve array bounds will be to do the following:

```
integer,target  :: a(2:4,2)
integer,pointer :: b(:)

b(lbound(a,1):) => a(:,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a straightforward extension of @VladimirF's answer.  Just put the pointer in a standard block and you will have pretty much the exact effect you are going for (e.g. the scope of the pointer is only local, as it would be for an associate block).

```
integer,target :: a(2:4,2)

block

    integer,pointer :: c(:)

    c(2:4) => a(:,1)

    print *, lbound(c), ubound(c)    ! 2 4

end block
```